# When a piston cylinder system that evolves isothermally and quasistatically is irreversible?

Tags: thermodynamics, entropy

Suppose we have two states: $\ce{A}$ and $\ce{B}$.
Considering a quasi-static isothermal process of an ideal gas, (and another condition, that is $T = T_\mathrm{surr}$) that join those states.

Then the Poisson's relation $P_\ce{A}V_\ce{A} = P_\ce{B}V_\ce{B}$ is fulfilled.
that means *after integrating*

$$W = nRT\ln\left(\frac{V_\ce{B}}{V_\ce{A}}\right)$$

$$\mathrm{d}S_\mathrm{s} = -\mathrm{d}S_\mathrm{surr}$$

because $T = T_\mathrm{surr}$. Then

$$\mathrm{d}S_\mathrm{u} = 0.$$

So my guess is that no, that irreversibilities on those conditions come only on finite temperature difference with surroundings.

But then I remember friction. If piston with friction has $x$ joules lost by friction, how does that change everything?

I need someone to "shed light" on this issue. There is always a lot of confusion when we consider a quasi-static but irreversible process.

Comment: With piston friction present, the situation does indeed change for both the quasi static and the non-quasistatic cases.  @BobD and I have been working on problems of this type in another forum:  https://www.physicsforums.com/threads/thermodynamics-gas-expansion-with-piston-friction.963282/  Maybe you would like to see what we have done so far, and join in?

Comment: Thanks I'll take a look, kinda confusing when friction appears.

Comment: So, when friction appears it seems that work cannot be calculated using Psystem=Pexternal ... But it is OK for internally reversible processes?

Comment: I don’t quite follow the question, but you can see some actual problems analyzed in detail in the link I referenced.  And it addresses the issue of precisely what one identifies as the “system” (which goes along with what one identifies as Pexternal).  Please feel free to post in that thread.

Answer (score 1):

If it is done quasi statically with friction involved and, if the system is in contact with a constant temperature bath at the initial system temperature T, then, for the same volume change, the change in entropy of the system will be the same.  That means that all the entropy generated as a result of frictional irreversibility will be transferred to the surroundings (the constant temperature bath).  This will be equal to the frictional work divided by the temperature T.  So the entropy of the universe will increase by this amount.

Comment: Got it, thanks. An external irreversibility.

Comment: Yes, if you want to call it that.  I've never heard this term used before.  Also, if you define your system as the gas, cylinder, and piston (rather than just the gas), then the irreversibility is internal to the system.  Of course, that doesn't change the answer to the problem.